# Default Sitecore Index Provider

Tags: indexing

After installation and setup of a Sitecore project, what index provider does it use? Lucene or SOLR?

How can I also find if my Sitecore project is using either?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the Sitecore version you use.

In the past it was always Lucene.

For modern Sitecore versions (e.g. Sitecore 10.x now) it's Solr.

You can open `web.config` file in your wwwroot and search for `search:define`

```
<add key="search:define" value="Solr" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Christian If the answer worked for you, mark it as valid so other users can benefit as well

Comment: yup, just waited to allow marking answer as correct. thanks again!